# Referral Traffic from d-xxx.ampproject.net (such as d-104013771329548540.ampproject.net)

Tags: amp-html

Recently, there were many changes on the AMP traffic to my website (lost traffic from   www-domainname-com.cdn.ampproject.org and started gaining traffic from just ampproject.org !!) and the most strange change is that we get referral traffic (measured with Google Analytics) from a bunch of domains such as the following:

````
d-4159656841268137597.ampproject.net
d-21453408932652834571.ampproject.net
d-2313567738935443475.ampproject.net
d-28118458413515555832.ampproject.net
d-3217094261111087989.ampproject.net
d-3321929344190779555.ampproject.net
d-33721989923345092911.ampproject.net
d-7209495481379958388.ampproject.net```

Any ideas on what is this???
````

Answer (score 0):

This is the AMP cache, don't worry.

Here is my filter to merge this D-xxx cache referrer to ein source:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @lovntola for the answer. I don't get it how someone (or several people) could be in these URLs and then visiting the website so that they create actual traffic ... Should if filter this out ? Is there some kind of documentation on why the cache creates referral traffic ?

Comment: I have a filter in analytics that merge all the xxx.ampproject.net into one to see the refferer and destination. But what ever you need

Comment: Sure , this makes sense. What I'm also looking for , is of you have traffic from exactly that kind of format of referral URL. It is very weird and I can't find any kind of documentation that verifies what these domains are...

Comment: The D-xxx ist defferent from the source the request comes. It is a interner nummering from Goolge, so no document about ist aviable. 
I have added my filter for Analytics, I hope this helps.